# NUXT - Dynamic Nested Routes for classified ads structure

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm working on a classifieds site and I'm having some difficulties using dynamic routes from nuxt.js.

I would like to have something like this in the URL:

- base_url> category> state> city> slug
- app.com/eletronics/sp/sao-paulo/guitar-8381239

I created the structure as follows:

[image]

```
//_category.vue
<template>
     <NuxtChild />
</template>

//_state.vue
<template>
     <NuxtChild />
</template>

//_city.vue
<template>
     <section>
       <h1> City </h1>
       <ProductsListComponent />
     </section>
</template>

//_slug.vue
<template>
     <div>
       <h1> Product Details </h1>
       ...
     </div>
</template>
```

My ProductsListComponent.vue has all the logic to handle the parameters I get in the URL and filter them in the API, so I would like to redirect all traffic from category to city.

Could you help me with this issue? How should I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure but you will have to be seperate routes via `router.js`. If your issue is directly call child component in the page.

Comment: Hi, did you tried this one? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes May be useful in your case IMO.